How to create a v-table in VUE js with typescript , Vuetify?
I have some log data ,from which I have to construct a v-table from script part.
I'm having issue with appending the html tags to the v-table.
Here is the code which I tried
<template>
  <div>
    <v-table width="800" ref="LogTable">
    </v-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

const logRefData = ref("03/22 08:51:06 INFO  creating mailslot for RSVP" + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:51:06 INFO:  mailbox allocated for rsvp" + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:51:06 INFO: creating mailslot for RSVP via UDP" + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:51:06 INFO:   mailbox allocated for rsvp - udp" + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:51:06 TRACE:   entity for rsvp allocated and initialized" + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:51:06 INFO:   creating socket for querying route" + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:51:06 INFO:   no mailbox necessary for forward" + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:51:06 INFO:   creating mailslot for route engine" + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:51:06 TRACE:   ready to accept informational socket connection." + "\n" +
  "2024-05-07 08:52: 50 EVENT:   api request SENDER")

const logRefDataArray = ref(logRefData.value.split(/\r?\n/).filter(item => item));
console.log(logRefDataArray);

const LogTable = ref();

const renderLogTable = () => {
  console.log('Render data');
  const parentCont = LogTable;
  if (logRefDataArray.value.length) {
    parentCont.value.innerHTML = ``;
    for (const [i, log] of logRefDataArray.value.entries()) {
      const tr = document.createElement("tr");
      const td = document.createElement("td");
      const logStamp = log.substring(0, log.indexOf(': ') + 1).split(' ');
      console.log(logStamp)
      let logStampData = '';
      if (logStamp.length) {
        const date = logStamp.splice(0, 1);
        const time = logStamp.splice(0, 1);
        const logType = logStamp.join(' ');
        logStampData = `<span>${i + 1}.</span><i>${date} ${time}</i> <b>${logType}</b> `;
      }
      const logMessage = log.substring(log.indexOf(': ') + 1);
      const logToPrint = `${logStampData}${logMessage}`;
      td.innerHTML = `${logToPrint}`;
      tr.appendChild(td);
      parentCont.value.appendChild(tr);
    }
  } else {
    parentCont.value.innerHTML = `<tr><td class="no_entry_found">No logs found</td></tr>`;
  }
}




onMounted(() => {
  renderLogTable();
});


</script>


I was able to get the table data successfully when I was using "document.getElementByID". But I want more of vue js, typescript instead of plain HTML/JS. So I have changed the code using ref.
I'm getting the error "TypeError: parentCont.value.appendChild is not a function". How do I resolve this error? Is there any better way to do this? How can we using v-html here?

That's not the way to work with vue, you should avoid manipulating the DOM in that way. I think you have started to implement vue without being clear how it works, I recommend you to read the official documentation https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html and also vuetify one https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tables/
I recommend that you parse the data to JSON/Array and step through it with a v-for
You should end with something similar to:
<v-table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Your header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="log in yourData">
      <td>{{ log }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</v-table>


@divya yes, please focus on the basics first: VueJS. Then you can add Vuetify to it. Finally TS. No need to do 3 things at the same time while being rushed. Also, you are not supposed to use v-html for something that you fully control. innerHTML is also very dangerous, use innerText if you one day very need to.
